# C# How to set a base class variable using a derived class variable before a method runs

Tags: c#, abstract, radix, derived

Only second question asked on here so if I'm missing some code that'll help just comment saying so.

I have an abstract class Report, a derived class of that called BusinessBreakdown and a derived class of that call BusinessWrittenBreakdown.

How can I change this code so that ReportTitle, DateField and DataLabel from BusinessWrittenBreakdown set the constructors of the same name in the BusinessBreakdown before BuildDefinition method runs.

I have tried googling and all but cannot work out how and this is as far as I got. The error that appears doesn't seem to help so I am more asking for a different approach that will work.

```
 public class BusinessBreakdown : Report
{
    static string ReportTitle;
    static string DateField;
    static string DateLabel;

    public BusinessBreakdown(string theReportTitle, string theDateField, string theDateLabel)
        : base(BuildDefinition)
    {
        ReportTitle = theReportTitle;
        DateField = theDateField;
        DateLabel = theDateLabel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build the report definition
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ReportDef BuildDefinition(Settings settings)
    {

        // Create definition
        var rdef = new ReportDef();

        // Create configuration context
        var context = new FsConfigContext();
        rdef.ConfigContext = context;

        // Report title
        rdef.ReportTitle =  ReportTitle;

        // Create report date range configuration
        ConfigDateRange drange = new ConfigDateRange(settings, "ReportDate", Config.ConfigDisposition.Filter,
                                      new FilterExpressionDef
                                      {
                                          Expression = DateField
                                      }, DateLabel); 

        rdef.ReportDate = drange;

///// code ...

        return rdef;
    }
}
}


public class BusinessWrittenBreakdown : BusinessBreakdown
{
    // Report title
    static string ReportTitle = "Business Written Breakdown Report";
    // Report date range and label
    static string DateField = "COMMISS.BRDateWritten";
    static string DateLabel = "Written Date";

    public BusinessWrittenBreakdown() 
         : base(ReportTitle, DateField, DateLabel)
    {
    }         
/// more code...   
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are your fields static?

Comment: You say you get an error, but don't say what, or where it is.

Comment: its unclear what you are asking.  Can you provide an example of what you are wanting to happen?

Comment: "... from BusinessWrittenBreakdown set the constructors of the same name in the BusinessBreakdown..."  I'm not sure how to parse "set the constructors".  Could you please try to clarify what you would like to happen a little bit more?

Comment: Making those properties static means that they will be shared between all instances of the class. There's no good reason to do that. They're set in the constructor, which means they are meant for that one instance of the class. If this was to run in a multithreaded environment like a web app or WCF service then these values would be changed unpredictably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely cannot control that sequence. This is a `static` method.

```
public static ReportDef BuildDefinition(Settings settings)
```

By definition, someone could call this method without *ever* calling the constructor of either class. So it follows that there's no way to make them call the constructor first.

Static properties and methods are shared between all instances of a class. That you have a constructor with these different properties suggests that you want to create one instance of the class for one report, then create another instance with different parameters for another report.

In this case it doesn't look like you need static methods, and they're only adding complication. So I would just remove `static`. That means every property or field is an "instance" property or field. It belongs to each individual instance of the class rather than being shared between instances of the class.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I haven't programmed much for a year since University and forgot some simple stuff. 
Will the rest of the code work without it being a static method or will I need to change the way I'm getting the variables?